# Detecting the location using GPS in Android takes much time

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, locationlistener

I have created a app which detects out location and redirects to the corresponding wiki page to read.
My coding working fine and detects correctly but it takes so much time to read our current location and to display.
Is there any way to detect it soon and display?

help would be appreciated.
my coding is as follows

```
private class LocationTrack implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String counName=null;
        String cityName=null;
        String localityName=null;
        Double lat=loc.getLatitude();
        Double lon=loc.getLongitude();
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses=gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
            Address obj=addresses.get(0);
            localityName=obj.getLocality();
            counName=obj.getCountryName();
            cityName=obj.getAdminArea();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t1.setText(localityName+","+counName+","+cityName);
        t2.setText(lat+"/"+lon);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                browser.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The GPS has a cold start, It takes time to obtain the location.
The better way is obtaining the last known location.
If you don't think you require the realtime location then better to use this.

Comment: How to add code like if location not changed, use the last location?how to use "getLastKnownLocation" in the code?

Comment: Yeah, This will return the last known location and will be updated when other app will access the location using GPS.